# inserting into an array rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a record and I want to inset it inside and array and later access it.

```
users = User.all

results = []

users.each do |user|
  results << {:name => user.name, :email => user.email}
end
```

is results variable still an array ? If yes how can I get all the names alongwith email?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example would create an array `results` filled with hashes containing each users name and email.

You could access it in several ways, the easiest of which is a simple loop:

```
results.each do |result|
  name = result[:name]
  email = result[:email]
end
```

You can also access individual items directly like so:

```
first_result_name = results[0][:name]
```

but be careful of trying to access results that may not be there.

- [Arrays](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Array.html)
- [Hashes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html)

But I have to ask, why do you want to do this? There's no gain from assigning all the `User`s name and emails to an array, User.all is no different really in functionality.

Comment: how can I access all the results, I just want to do results

Comment: So in what form do you want them?

Comment: Explain what you want to do with the results and we can give a more targetted answer.

Comment: I am using it with autocomplete, so I want to access all the results in the suggestion box at once, I am using it with typeahead.js

Comment: Check out [this gem](https://github.com/crowdint/rails3-jquery-autocomplete), it supposedly works with collections, alleviating this (frankly silly) collection to array step. To pass this `results` array to the view you just need to use it with an @ sign: `@results = []`, `@results << ...`

Comment: actually I want to do autocomplete across multiple models, this gem works only for single model

Comment: So just use `@results` instead of `results` and the array will be accessible in your view.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's still an array. You can have what you want later for example with:

```
results.each do |result|
  result[:name] # access to name
  result[:email] # access to email
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need one line to do it

```
results = users.collect{|user| {:name => user.name, :email => user.email}}
```

Answer (score 0):

In a kind of unrelated way, your initial code could be rewritten as:

```
results = User.all.inject([]) do |array, user|
  array << {:name => user.name, :email => user.email}
end
```

Given that "results" now contains this collection of hashes, if you want to print every user name and email you would do:

```
results.each do |user|
  puts "#{user[:name]} #{user[:email]}"
end
```